# Punctured sphere is homeomorphic to punctured plane

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let ${S}$ be a sphere with $n$ points removed and let $X$ be the plane $\Bbb{R}^2$ with $n-1$ points removed. Explain $\pi(S)\cong \pi({X})$.

I want to know the intution(physical and mathematiccal) to understant why $\pi(S)\cong \pi({X})$?

Comment: The sphere is just the plane with one point added! If that's hard to grasp, can you understand that 1) the sphere with its north pole missing is homeomorphic to a disc, and that 2) the disc is homeomorphic to the plane?

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos Could you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Elaborate on what exactly? The two homeomorphisms I gave as a hint?

Comment: I see. By transitivity of the homemorphism $\pi(S)\cong \pi(X)$. Thanks!